# Finding matches using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

How to find the length of consecutive zeros that is surrounded by ones at both ends of a binary?

For example, in `10010001` the 2 matches are 1001 and 10001

- 1001  the length of zeroes is 2
- 10001 the length of zeroes is 3

I used match which returned only the last one i.e. 10001.

```
'1010001'.match(/1(0+)1$/g)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Regex, I would keep it simple.

1. Split the string on '1's
2. Get the length of each section
3. Remove the first and last section length because they aren't surrounded by '1's
4. Find the highest section length

```js
const maxNumberOfZeros = Math.max(...'000000101000100000'.split('1').map(str => str.length).slice(1, -1));
console.log(maxNumberOfZeros);
```

Comment: This will failed with the test: '101000'.

Comment: @DanielTran Good catch! I didn't read the question carefully enough :), I have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need lookahead assertions here:

```js
console.log('1010001'.match(/10+(?=1)/g).map(function(x) {
   return x.length - 1;
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

First, replace all '1' by '11', then remove $ - from your regular expression.

```js
console.log('10010001'.replace(/1/g, '11').match(/1(0+)1/g));
```

Comment: That worked. But I dint follow what was the purpose behind changing the 1's to 11. Can you please explain.

Answer (score 1):

In regular expressions, `$` is a special character matching the end of the string ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)).

But that's only half the problem. `String#match` captured the trailing 1 in the first group and could not create a second overlapping group for '10001'. Try using [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) instead. The regular expression is stateful, and in this case, you'll want to move the last index back one for each match you find.

```
var re = /10+1/g;
var str = '10010001';
var matches = [];
var result;
while ((result = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  matches.push(result[0]);
  re.lastIndex--;
}
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(N) {    
    let s = (N >>> 0).toString(2).split('');

    let max = 0;
    //1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
    if(s.length > 2){

        let lastDigit = s[s.length - 1];
        let firstDigit = s[0];

        while(lastDigit == '0'){
            s.pop();
            if(!s.length || s.length == 1) return 0;
            lastDigit = s[s.length - 1];
        }

        while(firstDigit == '0'){
            s.shift();
            if(!s.length || s.length == 1) return 0;
            firstDigit = s[0];
        }
        
        let x = s.join('').split('1').filter(i => i !== '').sort().reverse();

        return x.length ? x[0].length : 0;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `$` within `RegExp` matches end of string.

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` and logic to evaluate `1` and `0` as a `Boolean` to determine if the sequence matches the required pattern

```js
let nums = ["1000000001010001", "0000000101", "100000000"];
let countZerosBetweenOnes = str => 
  (res => ([...str].reduce((a, b, idx, arr) => 
    (!!+a && !+b && arr.find((n, i) => i > idx && !!+n) && res.push(+a)
    , !+a && !+b && res.length && ++res[res.length - 1], b))
    , res.sort((a, b) => a - b).pop() || 0))([]);

nums.forEach(n => console.log(countZerosBetweenOnes(n)));
```

Comment: Fails for `0000000101`.